# Align Ranks in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, rank

This is a follow-up question to [How can I achieve strict reverse ranking of graphviz dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396374/how-can-i-achieve-strict-reverse-ranking-of-graphviz-dot), but a little easier. This graph is contrived, but demonstrates the problem:

```
digraph nfa {
    A -> B
    B -> C
    C -> D
    D -> E
    A -> F
    F -> E
}
```

Nodes B and F are the same rank, but they are not displayed at the same rank. How can achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used subgraphs with `rank = same`, and manually computed the ranks and grouped them in said subgraphs.

```
digraph {
    { rank = same; A }
    { rank = same; B; F }
    { rank = same; C }
    { rank = same; D }
    { rank = same; E }
    A -> B
    B -> C
    C -> D
    D -> E
    A -> F
    F -> E
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An "easier" solution, using the new-ish **TBbalance** attribute (http://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/TBbalance/).  TBbalance does just what you want.

```
digraph nfa {
  TBbalance=min
    A -> B
    B -> C
    C -> D
    D -> E
    A -> F
    F -> E
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Nice solution, you wrote "using the new-ish TBbalance attribute", do you happen to know since which version this is available?

Comment: I do not.  I believe it was first introduced ~4 years ago, but was buggy.  Improved version was introduced ~ 1 year ago.